# Pygame key.set_repeat() not working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to write a simple map editor and I'm running into a problem with pygame.set_repeat(), I have it set before the while loop but have also tried it IN the while loop and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I've checked other threads but haven't found anything that helps.
Could anyone give any input?

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import os
import os.path

from pygame.locals import *
from classes.tile_sprites import sprites
from classes.tile_sprites import buttons

class MainCode:

    def main(self):
        size = width, height = 800, 600
        display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        button_location = "../resources/images/buttons"
        icon_location = "../resources/images/icons"

        surface_type = {"track":os.path.join(icon_location, "track.png"),
                         "dirt":os.path.join(icon_location, "dirt.png"),
                         "grass":os.path.join(icon_location, "grass")}

        incline_type = {"steep_incline":os.path.join(icon_location, "steep_incline.png"),
                        "moderate_incline":os.path.join(icon_location,"moderate_incline.png"),
                        "flat":os.path.join(icon_location, "flat.png"),
                        "moderate_decline":os.path.join(icon_location, "moderate_decline.png"),
                        "steep_decline":os.path.join(icon_location, "steep_decline.png")}

        surface_selections = ["track", "dirt", "grass"]
        incline_selections = ["steep_incline", "moderate_incline", "flat", "moderate_decline", "steed_decline"]

        tile_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        button_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        selected_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()

        sbl = buttons((25, 25), (0, 255, 0), "left")
        sbl.rect.x, sbl.rect.y = 0, 0
        sbr = buttons((25, 25), (0, 255, 0), "right")
        sbr.rect.x, sbl.rect.y = 100, 0
        ibl = buttons((25, 25), (0, 255, 0), "left")
        ibl.rect.x, ibl.rect.y = 0, 100
        ibr = buttons((25, 25), (0, 255, 0), "right")
        ibr.rect.x, ibr.rect.y = 100, 100
        to_add = [sbl, sbr, ibl, ibr]
        button_group = self.pygame_group_add_many(to_add, button_group)

        pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1000000000)

        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[K_DOWN]:
                print "down"

            display.fill((0, 0, 0))
            tile_group.draw(display)
            button_group.draw(display)
            pygame.display.flip()
            fps_clock.tick(30)

    def pygame_group_add_many(self, items_to_add, group):
        for each in items_to_add:
            group.add(each)
        return group

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainCode().main()
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your question... what is your actual output and what is your expected output?

Comment: Eventually this is going to be used to select items, at the moment I'm just printing when a keypress takes place and, as far as I know, with keyrepeat set I should be able to change the speed at which this happens, it isn't changing though.

Comment: Have you tried to turn this into a short, self-contained, compilable, example? http://www.sscce.org/ It will make it much easier for us to help here if you remove all the code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem (and you may even solve the problem yourself in the mean time!) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_pressed()` and `if key[K_DOWN]:` means that you keep pressed `K_DOWN` and you didn't "unpressed" it. `get_pressed()` has nothing to do with `set_repeat()`.

`set_repeat()` works with events.

This code will print "event down" only once when you keep pressed `K_DOWN`

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_DOWN:
        print "event down"
```

If you add `set_repeat(1,1000)` it will print "event down" every 1000 miliseconds when you keep pressed `K_DOWN`

Full example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600) )

pygame.key.set_repeat(1,1000) # add/remove this line

running = True        
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                print "EVENT DOWN"

pygame.quit()
```